# schema validationError FastAPI & pydantic

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am creating a API using the FastAPI framework and my post request payload looks something like this

```json
{
    "batch_id": "7r3683693242",
    "queries": [
        "What is the capital of Germany",
        "How is Electricity generated"
    ],
    "num_items_to_return": 2,
    "passage_id_and_score_matrix": [
        [
            ["16278720_0", 0.8], ["169339_0", 0.6]
        ],
        [
            ["19258753_14", 0.6], ["3270043_12", 0.4]
        ]
    ]
 }
```

I have defined my pydantic model as

```py
class ReRankerPayload(BaseModel):
    batch_id: str
    queries: List[str]
    num_items_to_return: int
    passage_id_and_score_matrix: List[List[Tuple[str, float]]]
```

and my API signature

```py
@app.post("/rerank-passages")
async def rerank_passages(payload: ReRankerPayload):
    response = reranker.get_results(
        payload.batch_id, payload.queries,                                    
        payload.passage_id_and_score_matrix, 
        payload.num_items_to_return,
    )
    return response

uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, log_config=None)
```

When I open the swagger page which is hosted on `127.0.0.1:8080/docs` I am getting the following error

```
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/buddy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/buddy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/buddy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/buddy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 656, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/buddy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 259, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/buddy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 61, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/buddy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 161, in openapi
    return JSONResponse(self.openapi())
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/buddy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 136, in openapi
    self.openapi_schema = get_openapi(
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/buddy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/openapi/utils.py", line 410, in get_openapi
    return jsonable_encoder(OpenAPI(**output), by_alias=True, exclude_none=True)  # type: ignore
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 362, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for OpenAPI
components -> schemas -> ReRankerPayload -> properties -> passage_id_and_score_matrix -> items -> items -> items
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
components -> schemas -> ReRankerPayload -> $ref
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

The above code works fine on fastapi version `0.65.2` but not on `0.70.0`. How can I make the above code work irrespective of the fastapi version

Comment: What happens if you set the type of 'passage_id_and_score_matrix' List[List[List[str, float]]]?

Comment: @noninertialframe, I am getting this error - TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.List; actual 2, expected 1, if you I the type of 'passage_id_and_score_matrix' as List[List[List[str, float]]]

Comment: Could you try List[List[List[Union[str, float]]]]?

Comment: This result in the following passage_id_and_score_matix - [['9808094', '0.8'], ['4494115', '0.6']], [['1792034', '0.6'], ['20974116', '0.4']], i.e. float converted to string

Comment: As a last resort, what happens if you pass in 
"passage_id_and_score_matrix": [
     [("16278720_0", 0.8), ("169339_0", 0.6)],
     [("19258753_14", 0.6), ("3270043_12", 0.4)]
     ]
 } 
to match the type "Tuple"

Comment: doesn't work either, Tuple is a python specific concept, not a valid JSON format. In the swagger page if I pass passage_id_and_score_matrix as above, I am getting HTTP code 422 (unprocessable entity)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tuples are currently [not supported in OpenAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/466).

There are a couple of way to work around it:

1. Use a `List` with `Union` instead:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Union

class ReRankerPayload(BaseModel):
    batch_id: str
    queries: List[str]
    num_items_to_return: int
    passage_id_and_score_matrix: List[List[List[Union[str, float]]]]
```

This is the quickest solution but won't ensure the number of items in the innermost list/array.
[image]

2. As suggested in the linked thread, you could use Pydantic's [`conlist`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#arguments-to-conlist):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, conlist
from typing import List, Union

class ReRankerPayload(BaseModel):
    batch_id: str
    queries: List[str]
    num_items_to_return: int
    passage_id_and_score_matrix: List[List[conlist(Union[str, float], min_items=2, max_items=2)]]
```

This would ensure that only two items can be passed in the innermost list, and that they are either a `str` or a `float`, however, it won't ensure the order.
[image]

3. If you can adapt the request body, consider changing it to something like:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List

class Entry(BaseModel):
    id: str
    score: float

class ReRankerPayload(BaseModel):
    batch_id: str
    queries: List[str]
    num_items_to_return: int
    passage_id_and_score_matrix: List[List[Entry]]
```

This improves readability and ensures that `Entry` always has exactly the two properties (`id` and `score`).
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer but option 1&2 are converting the float passed in the input to the API to string. Option 3 looks promising but for that to work I need to change inner tuple of passage_id_and_score_matrix to a dictionary format to make it work.